# Moderation Tools - undeletable post appears in delete candidates list

Tags: bug, moderation, 10k-tools

In the [10k Moderation Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) -> "Delete votes" -> "Most Votes" list, there appears [Sending emails in Node.js? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113701/sending-emails-in-node-js).

However, that post is locked and so not eligible for (more) delete votes, and so it should not appear in the list.

I suggest that either the list is filtered so that it does not show locked posts, or the delete votes are removed from locked posts.

Comment: I imagine this is going to be a rather rare occurrence so not sure what the best solution is for the future, but for this one for now, I've deleted the post and undeleted it, so it's current delete vote count is now zero.

Comment: @JonClements I didn't know that third option was available, but it would probably be better if the delete votes were automatically removed when a post is locked. It shouldn't take long to program... ;)

Comment: The thing is - apart from the historical lock - locks aren't meant to be permanent (most are just a hour/day/week) and even historical locks can be undone later... so it's not quite as clear cut as null the delete vote(s) when a post is locked...

Comment: @JonClements Ah, in that case my first suggestion of filtering the list so that it does not show locked posts appears to be the way to go. Would it have too much effect on the performance of the tools page?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so but I'm not an SO developer so I can't say for sure. It's going to be such a rare occurrence though - I'm doubtful if it's really something to worry about.

Comment: I feel that the best option is for the lock to have expiration date.

Comment: @Braiam Was this question brought to your attention by the Community♦ user, by any chance? I just suggested to someone elsewhere to ignore edits marked as "modified xx mins ago Community♦" - maybe it's becoming sentient and does not want to be ignored.

Comment: No. I just wanted to express my opinion of what should happen instead of what was the discussion between only two users.